# Is "Partial Connection" without VPN possible?

Tags: vpn, nat, firewall, ieee-802.11, ssh

I have come across a strange issue, and even as I type the question here, I wonder if folks will simply reject it as "impossible", but still, the experts here may have some inputs.

Recently I had been out of town, where I had to use a wifi dongle (MTS, in India, in case that matters). For web browsing and such, it worked fine. To connect to my office network, I used the normal vpn and then I could ssh to a server in US.
Next day, I started the ssh connection before connecting to vpn. Strangely, I got the username/password prompts, but even if I gave the correct password, it reported "Access Denied" consistently. That was when I noticed that I had not used the vpn. I quickly checked Ping and was shocked to see the responses.
After connecting to the vpn, it was business as usual.

In the evening, I again tried ssh without vpn, and again I got the username/password prompts + "Access Denied". With vpn, it worked fine.

Now my question is : **How did ssh (and ping) get connected to the US server, but access was refused ?**

**One possibility** was : Some sort of vpn cache was stored in the dongle.

**Another possibility** was : MTS was connecting to some other server where my username was invalid. I think this is more likely. If this is the case , then the local client will warning about the remote server host key change.

I am no longer out of town, so not able to analyse further.

EDIT:

The most probable situation seems to be "Another possibility" given above
 (supported by @YLearn & @toddWilcox) because the remote IP was 10.72.X.y in the private range.

Mean-while @generalnetworkerror has given the following :

**Yet another possibility** was : The remote server is reachable without vpn, but the authentication requires that the source IP Address belong to my company, not some outside IP address.

Comment: I think your "another possibility" is the most likely answer and might be where you have to leave it with no further ability to test.

Comment: You don't specify the IP address of the "server in US."  My first guess is that this IP address is likely from one of the reserved blocks for private use defined in [RFC1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918), and the primary reason you need to VPN into your company to reach it (as private IP address are not routable over the internet).  It was just coincidence that MTS was also using the same private IP address for a host reachable via SSH on their network.

Comment: Previous two comments _support_ "another possibility". Yes, the IP address was 10.72.X.Y, and MTS may have SSH enabled on a server with the exact same IP address. My username was invalid there, so "Access Denied".

Comment: Unless you hadn't connected before or your ssh client has nerfed security connecting to the wrong server would bring up a host key warning. Access denied suggests that you connected to the right server but were blocked by IP restrictions.

Comment: @PeterGreen , Nice Point !! I was not paying much attention , so not sure if I got the host key warning or not. I will add this to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your server is obviously reachable over the Internet without VPN as evident by you receiving a username/password prompt over SSH.  **I can only speculate that the "Access Denied" resulted from whatever authentication method is employed that checked your source IP address and refused to grant entry from a public IP.**

Had you been on VPN, assuming either split-tunnel or full-tunnel mode forced your access to that server through your company's internal network or back out through the Internet from a known location, the authentication would have permitted what was now seen as the source address belonging to your company, not where you sat [publically] on the Internet.

Comment: +1 for "yet another possibility". I will add this to my question.